# Make continuous numbered list in different lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have some data at {1} This is a test data {2 } This is another data. Notice space after two which was given by error {3} This is one more data { 4} Another space error before number

I want to make all in their own line with correct format as {1} i.e no space before or after digit

I need a regex for that for Notepad++

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `{\h*(\d+)\h*}`
- Replace with: `\n{$1}`  or `\r\n{$1}` depending on platform
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
{           # open brace
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
}           # close brace
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          # linefeed, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
{$1}        # content of group 1 (i.e. the digits) surrounded by braces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. What is want is that the each numbers along with its sentence should come on separate line. For some reason I am not able to put it on separate line here. Its all showing in one continuous line in superuser.

Comment: Something like this:
{1} This is a test data  <br/>
{2} This is another data. Notice space after two which was given by error  <br/>
{3} This is one more data  <br/>
{4} Another space error before number<br/>

Comment: @Shahid: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. I have accepted the anwer.